# how to load a configuration from a .yaml file to a class in java?

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I am using the snakeyaml library to load the yaml file but it shows me an error

[image]

this is the code from my Settings class, it has an Database object which represents the database settings

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

public class Settings {
    private final static InputStream file;
    private final static Settings parsedSettings;
    public Database database;
    static {
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("./src/main/java/com/example/settings.yaml");
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            parsedSettings = yaml.loadAs(file, Settings.class);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Settings file not found or cannot be readed");
        }
    }
    public Settings(){
        this.database = parsedSettings.database;
    }

    public class Database {
        private String driver;
        private String user;
        private String password;
        private String host;
        private int    port;
        private String name;

        private Database(String driver, String user, String password, String host, int port, String name){
            this.driver   = driver;
            this.user     = user;
            this.password = password;
            this.host     = host;
            this.port     = port;
            this.name     = name;
        }

        public String getDriver() {
            return this.driver;
        }
        public String getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }
        public String getHost() {
            return this.host;
        }
        public int getPort() {
            return this.port;
        }
        public String getDatabaseName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my settings.yaml file:

```
database:
  driver: mysql
  user: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  name: java_messages_app
```

I'm not using any framework, I'm only using libraries

I don't know if I have to load in the constructor or in static way.

Sorry for my english, I'm using google translator

Comment: The reason is that your `static` block loads the yaml file, in which snakeyaml attempts to create an instance of `Settings`. Take a look at what the constructor does and what may cause an Exception there. Just remove the assignment in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apache commons configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/):-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This has to be inside your code where you want the values to be read :-

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
config.load(PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
config.getInt("key");
```

Assuming your yml looks like this :-

```
key: value
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend loading the file in the `static` initializer.

This way, snakeyaml creates and instance of `Settings` which throws a `NullPointerException` because of the statement in the constructor.

I suggest this:

```
public class Settings {
    private final static InputStream file;
    private final static Settings parsedSettings;
    public Database database;
    public Settings() {} //or just remove this

    public static Settings loadFromFile() {
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("./src/main/java/com/example/settings.yaml");
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            return yaml.loadAs(file, Settings.class);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Settings file not found or cannot be readed");
        }
        return null;
    }

    //...rest of class
}
```

Now just call the `loadFromFile` method whereever you need your instance of `Settings`.